# linux: Changing default programs

Tags: linux, path, directory, default, redhat

I'm on a RedHat server as a --user

my github default is out of date (1.7.1)

```
>>which git
/usr/bin/git
```

However there's another git on the server
/appl/git/2.6.1/git

How do I change my default "which git" to refer to the one in the /appl folder every time I login?

I have tried(DOESNT WORK):

```
>> cd ~
>> vim .profile
export PATH=/appl/git/2.6.1:$PATH
```

Then reopen my terminal

Comment: do you just want to change the output of which, or do you want to **use** the git version in appl (e.g. when entering `git commit`)? if the latter, change the PATH variable by placing the /appl/... directory before the /use/bin

Comment: It's the second one, I updated my post with your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Add the folder /appl/git/2.6.1 to your PATH variable, before /usr/bin.

Comment: @user3711518 No, you didn't: you put it at the end, not before `/usr/bin`. The right way would be `export PATH=/appl/git/2.6.1:$PATH`.

Comment: I updated my .profile with this and reopnened, now >> echo $PATH gives /appl/git/2.6.1: ... :/usr/bin: ..., however, which git is still from /usr/bin/git

Comment: Bash Reference Manual says "A full search of the directories in $PATH is performed only if the command is not found in the hash table." So you may try hash -r

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to prepend your `~/bin` folder to the path and add a symlink to the `git` executable there:

```
ln -s /appl/git/2.6.1/git ~/bin/git
```

Comment: The /bin/git is in root, not in $HOME unfortunately, so I don't have permission to do such :/

Comment: I specifically talk about `~/bin`, i. e. the `bin` in your home directory. There you should be free to put whatever you want.

Comment: Ah okay, I don't have such directory by default. How will this change my default git?

Comment: @user3711518 Well, the same way as described: if you have a `~/bin` (easily feasible with `mkdir ~/bin`) and prepend it to the `$PATH`, any files inside it will be found first. If you add a `git` there (which may be a file or a symlink), it will be used.

Comment: That makes sense! I did this, and I now have a path to ~/bin/git!, I then export PATH=~/bin:$PATH However when I type which git it still finds it at /usr/bin/git ??

Comment: @glglgl maybe you wanna change your answer to "prepend" instead of "append" ?

Comment: @user3711518 What gives you `echo $PATH`?